# How to tile texture a curved model?

Tags: texturing, uv

The ground in this video is exactly what I'm trying to achieve:

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XPgRnLRxlJM

I'm currently just using simple materials which has a nice low poly look, but it's not very diverse. 
After I saw that I decided I wanted to texture my models just like that as well, so how would I go about doing that?
Whenever I try to UV unwrap, I just get terrible results, the shapes seem far too complex for me to even get a idea of how to do this.

Is there any easy way to do this?
So far, UV unwrapping has just been fustrating me.

Comment: Could you tell me what I might improve about my answer to make it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would try to look at the mesh from the top by pressing 7 on the numpad, and then U > Project from view. Then, scale down or up the parts of the mesh that curve the most.

[image]

Comment: I just made probably THE worst mistake one could probably make,.. I deleted all code from my game. So i havent had time to test your suggestions yet, i really appreciate it though and run some tests as soon as i can and get back to you

Comment: This seems to do the trick just fine, thank you so much! Allright now i can do some propper level design :D

Comment: Hey cool! If you don't mind, could you accept my answer for internet points?

Comment: @dude sign up for a github ac and backup your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this: select one quad face, then use "Follow Active Quads". I would suggest "Loop Average" for best results.